# Can I use the result of a SUM function in the WHERE clause of SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example suppose I have

```
SELECT sum(...) as total
```

Can I do something like

```
WHERE total > 10
```

When I try that actual syntax I get an error unknown column 'total' in 'where clause' using MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for conditions involving aggregates:

```
SELECT SUM(somecolumn) AS total FROM sometable HAVING total > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

```
HAVING total > 10
```